# What issues does CakePHP cause when using the JanRain openid library?

Tags: php, cakephp, openid, janrain

I'm implementing an OpenID consumer, and utilizing the JanRain classes (2.2.2) is failing out of the box. Specifically, I'm seeing the following symptoms:

1. The consumer isn't able to correctly identify the openid_mode parameter
2. The consumer has trouble finding the return_to variable

I'm fairly certain CakePHP is causing the issue, as the sample code in the JanRain consumer example works fine, but it fails as soon as it's placed within a CakePHP controller.

I have noticed that CakePHP's dispatcher sets a $_GET[url] parameter that confuses the JanRain validation, but I've been able to get around that one (by unsetting $_GET['url']). I'm hoping someone out there may have a short list of tips/techniques to get CakePHP to play friendlier with the JanRain code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't quite understand your problem, but since I am successfully using the JanRain plugin for quite a while now, here is at least one tip I remember from when I set it up : Try lowering your CakePHP security setting from "high" to "medium" or even "low", at least for testing purposes.

If it doesn't help, and you think you know what part of your code is causing the issue, let me now, I'll provide you with my sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try the OpenID component for CakePHP [linked here](http://code.42dh.com/openid/) which is regularly updated and works

Ensure you have lib CURL and openssl extensions enabled